# How to write a function to create functions in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

Is it possible in Powershell to generate functions based on a set of input variables?  I've tried wrapping the conditions in script blocks and brackets to force evaluation, but at best I get this as the return:

```
The term 'function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, [...]
```

Otherwise the function appears to run, but the new function binding does not get created.

This does not work (nor does wrapping the body in `& {}`, `& ({})`, `& {()}`)

```
function gen-test ($test) {
    function get-$test {
        Write-Output "This is $test"
    }
}
```

I want the names to be generated based on the passed value, not predefined.

#### Context

I have to support multiple domains and am looking for a way to simplify the coding of functions to return specific information from them.  Currently I have sets of functions of the type `Get-<domain>Info` (one for each domain) where info depends on whether I want account settings, group membership, etc.

If there is no way to get this done, I will just have to fall back to `Get-Info <identification> -server <domain>` with a default domain to query.  However I intend to share these with my colleagues and I want to make it as simple/straightforward as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function using New-Item and the PSDrive Function:

Example:

```
Function New-Func{
    Param(
        $Prefix
    )
    $Code = @"
        # Your code here
        Write-Output "This is $Prefix"
"@
    $Name = "Global:Get-${Prefix}Info"
    New-Item -Path Function:\ -Name $Name -Value ([ScriptBlock]::Create($Code))
}
```